# UV Unwrapping inconvenience

Tags: texturing, uv

I have come upon a roadblock. I'm studying game development and we began this week with school. I got tasked to make a sort of vase or urn, which was easy enough to model. [image: solid urn]

This was all fine until I had the grand idea of texturing it, which requires a UV map obviously enough. So I put the seams in place though it may be questionable if I placed them effective… [image: Seams view in wireframe modus]

I unwrapped it using the lightmap pack and follow active quads to get a proper Island in the UV editor. I fiddled around for a while to get the flow properly for the larger part, but the tricky thing is the handles(?). They're, as you can see, shaped in an arch with a couple rings of faces through them which makes it challenging to keep a great flow of the texture. Technically speaking I would need some faces on the same place in the UV editor, but that would be "UV overlapping". Is that allowed anyway?

(Don't mind the upperhalf of the UV map, I wasn't completely done. The bottom is the larger part of the urn and the rest are the handles and the inner part.)

[image: UV MAP + bad flow]

My question to you is; Is there a way to properly unwrap the handles for a proper texture flow?

Thanks for reading in advance and a have a great day!

EDIT: 10-09-2018

I think I have solved it. With the use of cylinder-shaped object I first unwrapped it as a whole and that is just a big mess. So I used the lightmap pack! This makes it all kinds of small islands, but it is still messy! Then I took a decent sized face in the edit mode and made it the active face. As the experience users might guess, Yes! I did use the follow active quads function which still makes a mess, better, but a mess.

I had to do a little tweaking to get the islands properly so I just put on the snap tool and set it on snap to vertex (closest) it worked out eventually. Here's the final UV map!

[image: Final uv map]

I still wonder about a better method/workflow for it. It's quite the hassle. checking the correct angle of the faces in the uv and place them properly, Especially with a lot of small islands. If someone knows a better workflow please let me know!

Comment: Your unwrapping looks OK. Now texture it. If you now use a texture image you will probably notice the seams, you can either clean that up in texture painting or use texture painting to paint onto the image you have there now. You can setup an image as the [texture on a brush](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/texture_tex_mask.html).